# I need solution to a combinational probability problem

Tags: probability

Prob#1) 
Three points are selected at random from the circumference of a circle. What is the probability that the three points lie in the same quadrant?

my solution:

There are $91$ points in each quadrant from 0-90 $\implies \binom{91}{3}$
There are $4$ quadrants $\implies \binom{4}{1}$
There are a total of $360$ points on the circle $\implies \binom{360}{3}$
$$\implies P(3\text{-points in same quadrant}) = \frac{\dbinom{91}{3}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{360}{3}}$$

Prob#2)
What is the probability to get "5" exactly $3$ times in $8$ throws of a fair die.

my sol: 
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{5}{3}}{\dbinom{48}{3}}$$

Prob#3)
The probability to have exactly $3$ boys in a $5$ kids family, if
a) The birth rate of boy is equal to that of a girl
b) If birth rate of boy is $1/3$ and girl is $2/3$.

Comment: In the first problem, you should not assume that the points occur at multiples of a degree.  In the second problem, do you mean exactly three occurrences or at least three occurrences?

Comment: please elaborate for part 1 and as for second its exactly 3

Comment: For the first one, do you require that the three points be on one of the four quadrants defined by the usual coordinate axes or (more likely) are you just asking that all three lie in some quadrant (not necessarily in standard position)?

Comment: assume standard where there is no other info, and yes => "For the first one, do you require that the three points be on one of the four quadrants defined by the usual coordinate axes"

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: i know latex, its just that i am quite frustrated by such trivial problem that i am unable to answer

Comment: Both the second and third problem can be answered directly using [binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  For each, decide what counts as a "success," what the probability of a success on a single trial, and how many trials there are.  As a result decide what values of $n,k,p$ you should use in the linked formulae.  Now... for the first, see if you can do something similar, but keep in mind that they didn't specify *which* quadrant they should be in, just that they should all be in the same.

Comment: Don't be frightened by the length of the wikipedia article I linked.  You may use all of the information contained in it later or just satisfy your curiosities, but the only necessary information for you for now is contained within the first few sentences.

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: Let's start again from top, Is my sol to 1st problem correct? If not then please explain

Answer (score 3):

Each of these problems can be approached using the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The short explanation is that if we are conducting $n$ repeated independent identical trials of an experiment (*for example rolling a die multiple times*) with a specific event of the sample space being considered a "success" which occurs with probability $p$, the probability of seeing exactly $k$ successes will be:

$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

For an example, if I flip a fair coin $\color{blue}{\text{ten}}$ times, the probability that exactly $\color{green}{\text{three}}$ of the times I flipped heads (*remembering that the probability of a head is* $\color{orange}{0.5}$) will be

$\binom{\color{blue}{10}}{\color{green}{3}}(\color{orange}{0.5})^{\color{green}{3}}(1-\color{orange}{0.5})^{\color{blue}{10}-\color{green}{3}}$

In many of these problems that can be solved using binomial distributions you must complete the steps:

- Recognize that the problem can be described as a binomial experiment.  It must be a repeated number of trials whose outcomes are independent with a clearly defined "success" and a probability associated with success that remains the same for each trial
- Figure out how many trials occur, i.e. find the value of $n$
- Figure out what counts as a "success" in our current problem.  What are we wanting to keep track of (e.g. how many times we flipped heads, or how many times we rolled a five)
- Figure out the probability of success for each individual trial (e.g. if we roll the die once, whats the chance it lands on a five?)

From there, simply apply the formula and conclude.

---

Specific suggestions for your problems

1) As not very much information is given, it would commonly be assumed that the points are selected from the circumference of the circle uniformly at random according to a *continuous* distribution.  It is "almost impossible" (*opposite of [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)*) to have picked a point that lies exactly on the border between two quadrants, so you should be able to describe this as though each point lies in exactly one of the four quadrants with equal probability, namely $\frac{1}{4}$.  That is to say, $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to lie in the first quadrant, $\frac{1}{4}$ chance to lie in the second, etc...

Now... wait and see where the first point is placed.  What is the chance that the remaining two points are also placed in the same quadrant?

> $n=2,k=2,p=\frac{1}{4}$

2) This is exactly like my example above but with different values of $n$ and $p$.  How many times do we roll the dice?  What is the chance for a single die to be rolled as a $5$?

3) Exactly the same problem but with different values of $n,p,k$.

Comment: This is such a well-detailed and excellent response. Bravo.

Comment: I would add that this is a characteristically detailed and excellent response.

Comment: I am still stuck its like i have no brain at all. please help

Comment: @Campigone where in my answer did you get stuck?  Did you try to read it all?  Up to what point did you understand?  Unless if you are asked to prove the validity of the binomial distribution pdf, this problem really is just about following definitions.

Comment: @Campigone perhaps try [watching some youtube explanations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNLQuuvE9ug).

Comment: Ok this is what i got: $\frac{3!}{1!(3-1)!} (\frac{1}{4}) (\frac{3}{4})^2$

Comment: @Campigone what is that in reference to?  The first problem?  I already gave you the simplification that you need to only worry about the second and third points being in the same quadrant as the first point.  If you dislike making that leap in logic, then *add together* the four probabilities: Pr(All three are in quadrant1) + Pr(All three are in quadrant2)+...+ Pr(all three are in quadrant4)

Comment: @Campigone the value you wrote, $\frac{3!}{1!(3-1)!}(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{3}{4})^2$ corresponds to the probability that exactly one of the three points lied in quadrant 1 and the remaining two points lied in quadrants different than $1$.

Comment: For second I have: $\frac{8!}{3!5!} \frac{1}{6^3} \frac{5^5}{6^5}$

Comment: Once you fix formatting, that is correct.  [See this post for mathformatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Note in particular the syntax `\frac{a}{b}` produces $\frac{a}{b}$.  If you do not have braces, then it interprets the first single character after `\frac` as the numerator, regardless of if it is a parenthesis or otherwise.  So, `\frac123` is the same as `\frac{1}{2}3` and both produce $\frac123~~~\frac{1}{2}3$

Comment: For 3rd I have done similar but for 2part birth rate $p=\frac{1}{3^3}$ and $ q=\frac{2^2}{3^2}$